# Old style Android menu displayed when migrated project to Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, menu

I've migrated my project from Eclipse to Android studio.
When I run it I see an old style menu, like in the image.
[image]

My gradle file is:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.tmp"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
```

How can I change the menu to the modern style?

Comment: Sorry, but i don't see any menu (aka *ActionBar* or *Toolbar*). Car you give more details?

Comment: When I press the menu button, the old style (android 2 or less) menu is opened on the bottom part of the activity

Comment: Ok, but how is added your menu on your code? Are you using *AppCompatActivity*? Did you try to launch your app on a real device?

Comment: I use regular activity

Comment: Then it is not good, IMHO. Try to update your code using **com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1** and *AppCompatActivity*. Or try to change *targetSdkVersion* to 23. I don't have any idea of how is coded your menu / app, unless you provide some code.

Comment: Ok, just changed activiti to AppCompat and theme to @style/Theme.AppCompat.  
Lot of thanks

Comment: Mazel tov! Glad to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm just reporting my comment as an answer, it will be more visible in case someone stuck in the same problem.

Try to update your code using *com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1* and **AppCompatActivity**. Then use **@style/Theme.AppCompat** as theme.

Answer (score 1):

Just change the theme to

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault"
```

Or if you want you can use

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"
```

but in this case you must add `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0` in your gradle dependencies